# History Book on The Effect of Islam on Western Civilization

Tags: history, islamic-scholar

What books are there with respect to early Muslim scholars' works and their effect on Western civilization? I would prefer easy to read not too technical books.

Comment: I think you should focus on the kind of scholars you refer to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest books and essays written by **William Montgomery Watt** (14 March 1909 – 24 October 2006) who was a Scottish historian, Orientalist, Anglican priest, and academic.

especially He has a book named: **Islamic Surveys: The Influence of Islam on Medieval Europe (1972) ISBN 978-0-85224-439-5**.